# Microsoft flow to read data from excel sheet

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I'm working on POC where In email attachments I will get excel file.

I am trying to read that excel file using Microsoft flow and create item's in SharePoint list.
For each row there will be new records.

Please suggest some solutions or supporting articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break this task into two simple Flows:

1. Save email attachment to a document library.
2. Read Excel file from the document library and create new SharePoint list items

**1) Save my email attachments to a SharePoint document library**

Create a new Power Automate flow using a template called "**Save email attachment to a document library.**" Configure it according to your needs. For example, you can only monitor emails by specific subject, etc. You should also select a document library that will store your Excel files.

[image]

**2. Read Excel file from the document library and create new SharePoint list items**

Now that you have Excel files automatically deposited to your document library, you can create a new Flow. This flow will be triggered on "file created".

- Use **When a file is created** trigger
- Add **Get tables** action
- Add **List rows present in a table** action
- Add **Create Item** action

[image]

This should be enough to get the entire process working.

Comment: Thanks Denis Molodtsov, I have created above flow it is working for me